# Bit overflow when subtracting and adding. My video is confusing

Tags: overflow

I have two slides in a video that I'm watching that I'm confused about:

[image]

Why can no overflow happen when adding a positive and a negative? Give me an example?

and

[image]

Why is the first addition -8? Isn't it positive 8?

Answer (score 0):

The result of adding a positive number (say, P) and a negative number (call it N) together cannot be more positive than P or more negative than N.  Since N & P can be represented, their sum must be able to as well.  (And you can't prove something can't happen with an example.)

In the second slide, they are demonstrating that when overflow occurs, the value being represented does not correspond to what the value of the addition *should* be (because that value cannot be represented).

Comment: how is 1000 = -8?

Comment: Read up on 2's complement representation.